# How to Redirect Subdirectory Files to index.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I add following code to redirect all requests to index.php file in .htaccess  :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.php|)$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But there is .htm files in subdirectors not redirect to index.php.
How to redirect all files in subdirectorys to index.php?
Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to remove `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` because you are telling htaccess to NOT (because of '!') to not rewrite

Comment: I remove that but still subdirectory files not redirect to index.php

Answer (score 1):

As per the Apache documentation for DirectoryIndex, simply put the following in a .htaccess file in the same directory as index.php:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: i put this in .htaccess file but files in subdirectory nor redirect to index.php

Comment: By default apache will always look for any of the index files you list in the current folder. IF your subfolder doesn't have index.php, then index.html will be taken. If index.php file is missing in each folder, try placing it and accessing the page.

Comment: no my index.php file is in public_html and i want redirect every file to this file.

Comment: You might have to try something like
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d